# iReport - PageFooter band error in "Print When Expression"

Tags: jasper-reports

When I define `Print When Expression` to the `Page Footer` band as below I don't want to show this band in outer pages after page 1.
But what is happening is that all elements of this band are being hidden , but still showing a blank region in all the pages corresponding to the size of the `Page Footer` band.

Definition of `Print When Expression`:

```
new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals(new Integer("1")))
```

I'm using `iReport 6.1.1`

Comment: I have update the answer with some additional information... your problem is not solved... but at least you can know that there is no solution only work around.... : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pageFooter` is a fixed band,not allowed to overflow, the report engine calculates there size not on content but on the band height which means that it will always be present with the band height you set...

[Quoting](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/2732-0) Teodord jasper report staff

> "I'm afraid there is no solution for what you want to achive"

This is why in fact why jasper report introduced `lastPageFooter`, to enable the possibility to have a footer only on last page.

Furthermore there was a feature request for [firstPageFooter](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/2732-0)

but it is **Closed, No Change Required**

Your work around could be to use the `title` band (let it take the whole page..) or the `background` band, with a `printWhenExpression`

Comment: Title band only show as header of the first page. The best alternative is JasperReports implementing a "FirstPageFooter" band. :(